# Resizing layer when interface orientation changes?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, nslayoutconstraint, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing some simple app that supports both portrait mode and landscape mode. I have a view `UIView` that has its constraints set (called videoView), and that resize properly when interface orientation changes. On top of that view i have added custom layer that. That layer should follow view's frame, so when interface orientation changes, it should change too.

Problem is layers don't have constraints. I have done something like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoView.frame.size.width, self.videoView.frame.size.height);
}
```

It resizes layer properly, but it doesn't look good. First videoView resizes, and then after some delay layer resizes. I would like it to be one smooth transition. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
    print("Landscape")
} else {
    print("Portrait")
}
```

This will tell you if the device will is going to rotate before it happens. This is where you can run your code.

Comment: Sure but how do I know which size I should resize my layer to?

Comment: Are you wanting your layer to be the screen size or what? More info please.

Comment: Layer is added on top of the videoView. When interface orientation changes, videoView resizes. Layer needs to mimic that size, and resize to that size.

Comment: you can just change the frame as you were doing before. `previewLayer.frame = videoView.frame`

Comment: Thanks this is great!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update the view layout again using `setNeedsLayout` or forcing it with `layoutIfNeeded`? You're changing the frame right when it ends laying out the subviews so it will wait on the next update cycle to  apply the changes.

A better approach would be applying the frame on `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Good luck,
Francisco

Comment: I forgot to mention i treied also viewWillLayoutSubviews but to no effect